# Is there a difference in base64_decode function for different formats in PHP

Tags: php, base64

I'm trying to upload some images to server with following php function:

```
function upload($output_file, $base64_string)
{
        $ifp = fopen($output_file, "wb");

        $data = explode(',', $base64_string);

        fwrite($ifp, base64_decode($data[1]));
        fclose($ifp);

        return $output_file;
}
```

When i pass jpeg image to function, everything is ok, but when i pass .png or something else, uploaded image is corrupted.

Is there any difference in decoding base64 string for different file types?

Comment: Maybe , exist as symbol in base64 string

Comment: I would also question your `explode` function, why are you doing that ?

Comment: There is no more , symbols in string, and explode function is needed to remove data:image/png;base64 from string.

Comment: can you provide your full $base64_string that doesn't work

Comment: And where does `$base64_string` come from? I'm thinking it's also URL-encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()` aren't context-aware.
The Base64 format was not even made for efficiently displaying images on web pages in the first place - it just happens to be usable for that today.

Your problem is caused by mangled data - not necessarily corrupt, but what you're passing to `base64_decode()` isn't the result you originally got from `base64_encode()`.
I assume you're transmitting it over HTTP somehow and that often involves URL-encoding, which would encode `+`, `/`, `=` - perfectly valid Base64 characters.